# Where to find the artboard presets?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, artboard, document-setup, cc-2017

Where to find the artboard presets in Photoshop 2017? I searched *artboard* on the global search but it says it's not available.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't have artboards. What settings are you looking to change?

Comment: @GeoffBall Photoshop has had [artboards](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/how-to/design-with-artboards.html) for a while now

Comment: @GeoffBall Indeed, photoshop has had artboards for a while now. I think it's time to update your software :)

Comment: Time to update, indeed! Or at least, time to pay better attention. Thank you both.

Comment: watch this video for more information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkgsGhwG7rI

Answer (score 0):

#### Two ways to show the artboard presets

- Add a new artboard: `Layer` > `New` > `Artboard…`
- Select an artboard in the `Layers` panel and check the properties bar on top (or the properties panel)

*Or do you want to edit the presets?*

Answer (score 0):

You do all this from the **New** dialog window.

1. Choose `Artboard` from the dropdown menu...
2. Set the dimensions and options you want.....
3. Click the **Save Preset** button on the right.

Or if you want to remove a preset...

Select the preset from the `Artboard Size` dropdown menu and click the *Delete Preset* button on the right.

I can't find a location on my system where any *actual* artboard preset data is stored. It may just be in the preference file.

Answer (score -2):

Select the Artboard tool from the toolbox, then go to options. There are lots of presets available.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot?